# 'gradlew.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command, react native

Tags: android, react-native, gradlew

I am new to react-native / android development. I have created a react-native project. I have to run it on a real physical android device. I am following the react-native official documentation. When i do **react-native run-android**, i get the following error.

```
debug Running command "cd android && gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081"
'gradlew.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: spawn gradlew.bat ENOENT
```

I did check **adb device**, my device is attached with the system but i am unable to install/run the app on real android device.

Can anyone help me ? I am stuck on this issue for 2 days.

Comment: try downloading latest gradle distribution from /services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-bin.zip
set environment variable and then run 
gradle wrapper from your android directory

Comment: run : The term 'run' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of 
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. . . . getting this error. Can you kindly explain the steps in detail @AnusKaleem

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

1. Download latest gradle distribution.
2. Set path variables
3. From your cmd and inside android directory, run following command

   gradle wrapper

This will create necessary gradlew file inside your android directory.
After this try running your app on actual device again.